# index_not_found_exception - Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, nginx

In image #1, as you can see, I am getting a valid ES response on firing a GET request. However, if I try doing the same things through the NGINX reverse proxy that I have created and hit ***myip/elasticsearch***, it returns me the error (image #2). Can someone help me with this?

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name myip;

    location /elasticsearch/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9200;
    }
    location /kibana/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5601;
    }

}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right way is to specify both of those slashes. Slash after `127.0.0.1:9000` is essential, without it your request `/elasticsearch/some/route` would be passed as-is while with that slash it would be passed as `/some/route`. In nginx terms it means that you specified an URI after the backend name. That is, an URI prefix specified in a `location` directive (`/elasticsearch/`) stripped from an original URI (we having `some/route` at this stage) and an URI specified after the backend name (`/`) prepended to it resulting in `/` + `some/route` = `/some/route`. You can specify any path in a `proxy_pass` directive, for example, with `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9200/prefix/` that request would be passed to the backend as `/prefix/some/route`. Now if you understand all being said, you can see that specifying `location /elasticsearch { ... }` instead of `location /elasticsearch/ { ... }` would give you `//some/route` instead of `/some/route`. I'm not sure it is exactly the cause of your problem however configurations like

```
    location /elasticsearch/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9200/;
    }
```

are more correct.

Now may I ask you what you get with exactly this configuration in response to `curl -i http://localhost:9200/` and `curl -i http://localhost/`? I want to see all the headers (of cause except those containing private information).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the path. Nginx is passing it unmodified.

Add a slash at the `proxy_pass` urls.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name myip;

    location /elasticsearch/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9200/;
    }
    location /kibana/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5601/;
    }

}
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/):

> Note that in the first example above, the address of the proxied server is followed by a URI, /link/. If the URI is specified along with the address, it replaces the part of the request URI that matches the location parameter. For example, here the request with the /some/path/page.html URI will be proxied to http://www.example.com/link/page.html. If the address is specified without a URI, or it is not possible to determine the part of URI to be replaced, the full request URI is passed (possibly, modified).

Comment: I just realised that there wasn't a need to put an additional slash after the path. Hence, I removed `/` and now, it looks like `location /elasticsearch` . However, I keep getting the same exception with `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9200/` as well as `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9200`

Comment: It's working now. The slash after port number was important. There was a typo that I made while configuring. Thank you.